# Group by and fetch column that is not in group by clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have (sample) data:

```
equipment_id | node_id | value (type: jsonb)
------------------------------
1            | 1       | 0.3
1            | 2       | 0.4
2            | 3       | 0.7
2            | 4       | 0.6
2            | 5       | 0.7
```

And I want to get the rows that has max **value** within the same **equipment_id**:

```
equipment_id | node_id | value
------------------------------
1            | 2       | 0.4
2            | 3       | 0.7
2            | 5       | 0.7
```

There is query that does what I want but I'm afraid of performance degradation because of casting jsonb to float:

```
with cte as (
    select
       equipment_id,
       max(value::text::float) as val
    from metrics
    group by equipment_id
)
select cte.equipment_id, m.node_id, cte.val
from cte
join metrics m on cte.equipment_id = m.equipment_id and cte.val = m.value::text::float
```

How can I avoid casting?

Comment: Really (1, 1, 0.4)?

Comment: My mistake. Fixed. Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`

```
select * from
(
select *, row_number() over(partition by equipment_id order by value::text::float desc) as rn
from tablename
)A where rn=1
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (equipement_id) m.*
from metrics m
order by equipment_id, value desc;
```

If your value is actually stored as a string, then use:

```
order by equipment_id, value::numeric desc;
```